# Error while compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, compile, centos-7

Hi I'm trying to compile a kernel on Centos 7.

I've installed kernel-devel package, but it's failing as follows:

```
[root@centos7 3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64]# LANG=C make V=1
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/x86/syscalls all
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

It's a bit strange because sources from kernel.org has no that error...

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I forget that kernel-devel is just a Development package, is not the complete source kernel tree.

If someone wants to get the full source kernel tree from CentOS has to do:

```
yumdownloader --source kernel
```